# Zero Data still being logged in as successfull

Tags: php, authentication

Unfortunately in my Login form, entering no data what so ever, still comes up as Login Successful. Have I made any specific errors, or should I be adding more code? Thanks very much for your help

PHP

```
<table style= width:300px; border="0"; align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS - checklogin.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="Hockey Club";
$tbl_name="members";


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);



if($count==1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername];
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword];
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

and - login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
header("location:Index.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you are unsetting `$_SESSION['myusername']` before attempting to log the user in, otherwise your testing may be affected by old data.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: `$myusername=$_POST['username'];` But there is no element with `name` `username` in your form.

Comment: `$myusername];` shouldn't be valid syntax.

Comment: @Waleed Khan - Im a bit of a beginner to this, would you mind explaining in more detail what you mean. And how I should change the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should never store the password in its raw form in the database. If you are new to programming, there are lots of great user authentication scripts out there. Please study them before you create a production site in this manner.

Here is a great place to get started.

[Hashing a Password](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode)

And do not use mysql. use mysqli or PDO

Here is a google link to get you going: [User authentication](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20user%20authentication&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS487US487&aq=0&oq=php%20user%20aut&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)